Issue with derivation of fractional calulus from general Leibniz rule
I was deriving fractional calulus from general Leibniz rule, but unfortunatelly I do not get equation that gives true results. Equation is nearly similar to Cauchy's equation for repeated integration $f^{(-n)}(x)  =\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_a^{x} (x-t)^{n-1} f(t)
dt $. So I guess, I had to make somewhere a misteake, but I could't find it.
By using  general Leibniz rule
\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)&=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty} {{n}\choose{k_1}} \frac{d^{k_1}}{dx^{k_1}}f(x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{d^{n-k_1}}{dx^{n-k_1}}f(x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty} {{n}\choose{k_1}} \frac{d^{k_1}}{dx^{k_1}}f(x)^{2^{-1}} \sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty} {{n-k_1}\choose{k_2}} \frac{d^{k_2}}{dx^{k_2}}f(x)^{2^{-2}}
\frac{d^{n-k_1-k_2}}{dx^{n-k_1-k_2}} f(x)^{2^{-2}} \\
&=...\\
&=\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \left[ {{n-\sum_{i=1}^{i-1}k_i }\choose{k_i}}  \frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}} \right] \frac{d^{n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i}}{dx^{n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i}} f(x)^0 \\
&=\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty}  \frac{ n!   \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}}  }{(n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i)! \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i!}  \frac{x^{-n+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i}}{(-n+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i)!}
\end{align}
By using gamma function reflecting formula
$\displaystyle \sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty}   \frac{n!x^{-n+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i} sin(\pi (n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i) ) }{ \pi(n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i)}\frac{  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}}  }{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i!}
 $
Let's notice that $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$, so for $n \leq 0$ we can obtain equation
$\displaystyle  -\frac{n!}{\pi} \sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{x} t^{-n-1+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i}   sin(\pi (n-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}k_i) ) \frac{ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}}  }{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i!} dt
 $
Because $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$, we can extract it from sinus as $(-1)^{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i}$
$\displaystyle  - \frac{n! sin(\pi n)}{\pi} \sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x} t^{-n-1}    (-t)^{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i}\frac{ \prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}}  }{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} k_i!}
dt $
$\displaystyle  \frac{1}{(-n-1)!} \int_0^{\infty} t^{-n-1}\sum_{k_1,k_2,k_3...=0}^{\infty} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^{k_i}\frac{d^{k_i}}{dx^{k_i}}f(x)^{2^{-i}}  }{k_i!} 
dt $
$\displaystyle  \frac{1}{(-n-1)!} \int_0^{x} t^{-n-1} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} f(x-t)^{2^{-i}}  
dt $
$\displaystyle  \frac{1}{(-n-1)!}\int_0^{x} t^{-n-1} f(x-t)
dt $
And at this moment I was jest retired because if $t=x-t$ than $\frac{1}{(-n-1)!}\int_0^{x} (x-t)^{-n-1} f(t)
dt $

It is interesting. I tried to make it more readable but seems I could figure out what do you mean by for derivative of hight n?

I meant that you derivative some function f(x), n times

Can you please introduce some backgrounds or your motivation? Please put your words by editing the question or equations.
